How to find out the native library directory of an app?
I want to find out the directory where the native libraries of an app have been extracted to. The path structure will depend on the Android version. On Android 14 it will be something links this:
/data/app/~~7BZ-8zEDb3gzGGndbbDhg9==/com.some.app-GQePpzWb2GhdgZ8qftAnrH==/lib

On a rooted phone, this would be an easy task.
It's also possible via ADB and USB debugging:
adb shell dumpsys package com.some.app | grep legacyNativeLibraryDir

However, I want to know if there's a way to find out without rooting or activating USB debugging.

Install this app. It creates a file with UID, package name, app name and native library directory of all apps.

@IrfanLatif Thank you very much for your comment. :) However, I'm sure you understand that I don't think it's very sensible to install just any APK off of the internet. Would the app in question be compiled from one of the repos on your GitHub? https://github.com/mirfatif

Here are the total 94 lines of source code.
